# Собственная система маршрутизации на основе БД ASP.NET core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Всем привет и заранее спасибо) У меня есть следующее задание: "Создать веб-приложение, которое будет иметь возможность отображения иерархической структуры каталогов. Сделать: 1. БД для сохранения иерархической системы каталогов (папок). Наполнить БД данными из схемы внизу. 2. Веб-приложение для отображения структуры каталогов из БД. На веб-странице каждого каталога отобразить название и список дочерних каталогов (элементы из списка должны быть ссылками)."

Отображаться все должно примерно так (БД прикрепил ниже)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделать все нужно на ASP.NET core MVC. Вот я сделал БД (при чем не указано, какой именно она должна была, ее можно поменять):

```
CREATE DATABASE folder_structure_db;
USE folder_structure_db;

CREATE TABLE folder_paths (
    path_id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    [path] NVARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT('')
);

INSERT INTO folder_paths VALUES
    ('Creating Digital Images/Evidence'),
    ('Creating Digital Images/Resources/Primary Sources'),
    ('Creating Digital Images/Resources/Secondary Sources'),
    ('Creating Digital Images/Graphic Products/Process'),
    ('Creating Digital Images/Graphic Products/Final Product');
```

Одно из условий это то, что вложенность этих папок может быть бесконечно большой. Можете подсказать, как можна сделать похожую маршрутизацию? У меня есть идея: "прочитать все из БД, прочитать самую длинную строку, разделить ее, на ее основе сделать MapControllerRoute(...), далее сделать файл-шаблон для контроллера, сделать чтобы взависимости от уровня вложенности делалось N папок у View и N контроллеров", но как по мне это очень странный вариант) Заранее прошу прощение если это слишком очевидно или просто, я никогда не работал, и это для меня кажеться очень сложным) Спасибо если поможете.

Comment: `Одно из условий это то, что вложенность этих папок может быть бесконечно большой` у URL есть ограничения на длину, то есть условие на бесконечность невыполнимое, если только путь не будет передаваться через тело запроса, а не URL

Comment: Я думаю это условно сказали. Нужно хотя-бы до N-ой длинны это сделать... Если так, можете помочь?

Comment: Реализуйте дерево. А запрос будет GET и содержать что-то типа `/folder/{guid}`, по этому Guid будете в БД находить связанные с ним элементы. А вьюшку сверстать тоже не вижу никакой проблемы, обычный цикл по коллекции. В `OnGet` запихиваете получение по Id из БД, а в `OnPost` (т.е клик на ссылку) редиректите на новый пейдж, в котором так же будет срабатывать `OnGet` делающий тоже самое что и выше

Comment: @Kalmankantaja а разве можно так сделать, если за это будет отвечать контроллер? Извините если не очень понимаю)

Comment: @saibel203 контроллер это всего лишь класс который выполняет ваш код на какой-то HTTP запрос) почитайте про ASP.NET контроллеры

Comment: @Kalmankantaja попробую, спасибо огромное за помощь)